# assigning one ng-controller to two element not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs and I came to very funny oroblem:

I have the following code:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="table">
<div id="clcikbtn"
    style="background-color: black; width: 20px; height: 20px;"
    ng-click="addTable()"></div>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>item</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in typesHash">
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.price}}</td>
            <td>{{x.unit}}</td>
            <td>edit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the full version of code working well is as follow:

[working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0ZB2O4CYlKkuugF1fBY?p=preview)

As you can see there is just one ng-controller="table" in the body that controls both button and table and after clciking on the button a row would be added to the table but I want the above version as follow:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div id="clcikbtn"
    style="background-color: black; width: 20px; height: 20px;"
    ng-controller="table" ng-click="addTable()"></div>
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>item</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in typesHash">
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.price}}</td>
            <td>{{x.unit}}</td>
            <td>edit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see everything is the same but just we have ng-controller=table for both table and div and the code works when the page loads but then after when you click on button nothing happens, Here is the link to code:

[not working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/qs3B0kLo999pvZTTwoLb?p=preview)

I have no idea why the second version is not working, actually I need the second version working can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working.  Controllers are not singletons, you have simply created two controllers and two scopes.  Updating the value in one will not affect the other.  You will need to create a singleton to hold the values; in the angular world this would be best done with a `.factory()`.

### Edit

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/epnb8eo13ZAiKqdINYb9?p=preview) shows a full example with some code style improvements ;)

The factory could look like this:

```
.factory('tableService', function () {
  var dataContainer = [{
    name: 'sugar',
    price: 1,
    unit: 1
  }, {
    name: 'lemon',
    price: 100,
    unit: 2.5
  }];
  var service = {
    data: data,
    add: add
  };
  return service;
  function data() {
    return dataContainer;
  }
  function add(data) {
    dataContainer.push(data);
  }
})
```

Regarding your example, I would just simply wrap the whole table with its controls in one HTML element and one Controller.  Though the plunker I gave explains how to communicate between two controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot can you show it with piece of code then I can understand it better?

Comment: Thanks for your update yes it works well the only thing that confuse me is in this code .controller('TableController', function(tableService) {
      this.testData = {name: 'meat', price: 200, unit:3.3};
      this.typesHash = tableService.data();
      this.addTable = tableService.add;
      })
    ; I do not understand how add works without () since even we do not send any data as aparameter can you explain it?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply...  `this. testData = tableService.data()` makes `this.testData` equal to the return of the data function.  In other words `this.testData = dataContainer`

Comment: `this.addTable = tableService.add` (notice the lack of parenthesis) makes `this.addTable` equal to the add function.  In other words `this.addTable = function add(data) { dataContainer.push(data);}`.  You should use this pattern to avoid repeating yourself in many controllers that use the same service.

Comment: Hello again, Can you please take a look at this link as well and see if you can help: apparently no one can answer that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271929/autocompleted-text-in-textbox-does-not-add-to-table-completely

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with your second version (given what you're trying to accomplish).

When you a controller is injected by Angular, it instantiates a new instance of that controller *every time*. This means your code actually is using 2 different `table` controllers. For this reason, controllers cannot maintain data between instances. They play the role of a view model and maintain their own scope for the view assigned to it.

To illustrate the scopes, I put your code in the following snippet and moved the `ng-controller` up a level. You can see that clicking the first button will add to the first grid while leaving the second alone and vice versa.

```js
 var app = angular.module('app', []);


 app.controller('table', function($scope) {
   $scope.typesHash = [{
     name: 'sugar',
     price: 1,
     unit: 1
   }, {
     name: 'lemon',
     price: 100,
     unit: 2.5
   }];
   $scope.addTable = function() {
     var arr = {
       name: 'meat',
       price: 200,
       unit: 3.3
     };
     $scope.typesHash.push(arr);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="table">
    <div id="clcikbtn" style="background-color: black; width: 20px; height: 20px;" ng-click="addTable()"></div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>item</th>
          <th>price</th>
          <th>number</th>
          <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in typesHash">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.price}}</td>
          <td>{{x.unit}}</td>
          <td>edit</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div ng-controller="table">
    <div id="clcikbtn" style="background-color: black; width: 20px; height: 20px;" ng-click="addTable()"></div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>item</th>
          <th>price</th>
          <th>number</th>
          <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in typesHash">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.price}}</td>
          <td>{{x.unit}}</td>
          <td>edit</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Please see the Angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller
>   directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the
>   specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be
>   available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor
>   function as $scope.
>
> Use controllers to:
>
> 1. Set up the initial state of the $scope object.
> 2. Add behavior to the
>      $scope object.
>
> Do not use controllers to:
>
> 1. Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic.
>      Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects
>      its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives
>      to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.
> 2. Format input — Use angular form controls instead.
> 3. Filter output — Use angular filters instead.
> 4. Share code or state across controllers — Use angular services instead.
> 5. Manage the life-cycle of other components (for example, to create
>      service instances).

For these reasons, I would suggest using the same controller for the entire group of elements like the following:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="table">
    <div id="clcikbtn" style="background-color: black; width: 20px; height: 20px;" ng-click="addTable()"></div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>item</th>
          <th>price</th>
          <th>number</th>
          <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in typesHash">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.price}}</td>
          <td>{{x.unit}}</td>
          <td>edit</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but he above case is a simpler version of what I am going to do next and I need my button in another container and also I have at least 4 other controllers and I can not define them all in body so how can I have one controller in this scenario?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you plan to do? What are the other containers and controllers? Are they supposed to be entire views, modules that make up a larger view, etc?