# autocompleted text in textbox does not add to table completely

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am new to angularjs,

I have a textbox and I have a button and table:

whenever user click on add button the data in the textbox would be added to the table:
here is the link to my code:
[code](http://plnkr.co/edit/kq7eB4Y7DsiQBP3nqDfx?p=preview)

everything works fine, but when it comes to autocomplete it starts acting funny,
the autocomplete itselfe works fine but if for example add acti and the autocomplete suggests actionscript then if instead of writing the whole word you choose it from suggestins just he characters that you typed would be added, for example in this example acti instead of actionscript.

also here is my code:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('Service', function() {
    var typesHash = [ {
        id :1,
        name : 'lemon',
        price : 100,
        unit : 2.5
    }, {
        id : 2,
        name : 'meat',
        price : 200,
        unit : 3.3
    } ];

    var localId = 3;
    availableTags = [
                      "ActionScript",
                      "AppleScript",
                      "Asp",
                      "BASIC",
                      "C",
                      "C++",
                      "Clojure",
                      "COBOL",
                      "ColdFusion",
                      "Erlang",
                      "Fortran",
                      "Groovy",
                      "Haskell",
                      "Java",
                      "JavaScript",
                      "Lisp",
                      "Perl",
                      "PHP",
                      "Python",
                      "Ruby",
                      "Scala",
                      "Scheme"
                    ];
    var service = {
        addTable : addTable,
        getData : getData,
        complete:complete


    };
    return service;
    function complete(){
        $( "#txt" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,
          messages: {
              noResults: '',
              results: function() {}
          }
        });
        } 
    function addTable(name,price) {
        typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:name, price:price,unit:1});
    }
    function getData() {
        return typesHash;
    }
});
app.controller('table', function(Service) {
    //get the return data from getData funtion in factory
    this.typesHash = Service.getData();
    //get the addtable function from factory 
    this.addTable = Service.addTable;
    this.complete=Service.complete;
});
</script>
```

can anyone help?
(also it is noteworthy that this is a smaller version of my project and for some reason I used factory)

Update:

one way is to use :

```
  typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:$("#txt").val(), price:price,unit:1});
```

instead of :

```
  typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:name, price:price,unit:1});
```

But I am sure there is a better way... Any idea?

Comment: i not much know about the angular factory, however i do know why input does not same as the object inserted. This is because u update the value by javascript, not from angularjs. therefore although from your eye is "ABC", but in angularjs is "A". u need to update the angular model. the following is similar to your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316937/bootstrap-datepicker-not-binding-with-angularjs-ng-model

Comment: Thank u but I could not make my code work with that probably because I am new to angular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey sorry Hamed Minaee I am little late but here is the solution for you :-

You need to add

```
    $("#txt" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
     $scope.tableTools.inputData=ui.item.value;
    } );
```

And remember to pass `$scope` to the service for controller updation by service.

Plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/RqTDNRHpUicmFPsYsQR9?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot awesome:). Can you explain a little bit about this line: $("#txt" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
           $scope.tableTools.inputData=ui.item.value;
          } );
          } for example what is autocompleteselect or where did you get ui and event?

Comment: This is a event which will call when you select the element from the list of elements inside the dropdown menu of autocomplete.In ui you have the selected item and i just used its value by calling ui.item.value
Hope its clear now.

Comment: And if you are satisfied please accept the answer and here http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ at the end you can find more events which you can use .

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Comment: Just another quick question: I always thought this tableTools.inputData is part of factory not scope but you used it as scope can you just explain it a littile bit?

Comment: You are binding value in HTML ng-model="tableTools.inputData" it binds to $scope but this plugin is jquery plugin so it deals with id="txt" which is not binded to angular js thats why i passed $scope to service to bind it with angular js.

Comment: Hello again squiroid can you take a look at this post as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388286/sending-array-by-ajax-call-in-angular-js/28388355?noredirect=1#comment45115068_28388355

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is: angular doesn't aware of the update made by jquery 
plugin

So when you change the input text via  `$( "#txt" ).autocomplete(...` the angular not aware about the change, so your "`inputData`" not update!!

To emphasize the problem, here [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FBV6iLdy3IIMhIPRlOw?p=preview) that print the `inputData`, as you can see when you select from autocomplete ***it still not updated***, and because you take the info from  `inputData` to the table, you get the undesirable item!.

**The solution:**
you need to build a `directive` that `apply` your changes to angular.
Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612650/ng-model-is-not-updating-when-using-jquery-element-val) it's may help you

Comment: Thanks a lot now the problem is more clear the only problem is I am using factory and I do not how to apply .directive inside factory to make it work