# sending array by ajax call in angular js

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I use the following code to send some information to my servlet to process data:

```
 $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/purchase/AddInfo",
                data: {
                    addArray : "sample"
                }
            })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                     typesHash.push( {id:data.id,name : data.name, price : data.price,unit:2.5 });
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 

                });
```

and it works perfectly;
but as you can see I want to send the parameters as an array not a string , lets say I have an array as follow:

```
  var typesHash=[
                 {id:'1', name : 'lemon', price : 100,unit:2.5 },       
                 {id:'2', name : 'meat', price : 200,unit:3.3  }];
```

now I want to send this array to the server, one quick and ugly way is to loop through the array that I have and send send the information as an string but I believe there should be a better way , can any one help?

Update: as it is suggested I changed my code to the following :

```
 $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/purchase/AddInfo",
                    addArray : typesHash

            })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                     typesHash.push( {id:data.id,name : data.name, price : data.price,unit:2.5 });
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 

                });
```

But I get null when I try to rceive it and this is how I receive it in my servlet:

```
String arr= request.getParameter("addArray");
    System.out.println(arr);
```

***Update 2:Here is the most updated code***

My servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String actionType = request.getParameter("addArray");
    System.out.println(actionType);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String str = "{ \"id\": \"1\",\"name\": \"ali\",\"price\": \"100000\"}";
    // System.out.println(str);
    out.println(str);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);

}
```

My js:

```
 $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/purchase/AddInfo",
               data: { addArray : typesHash } 


            })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                     typesHash.push( {id:data.id,name : data.name, price : data.price,unit:2.5 });
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 

                });
```

Comment: Hmm, I see! I think this is what you need https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Hey what is the output of this line "System.out.println(arr);" in servlet console? And don't use get use post because get has size limit in java.

Comment: And one more thing this line  addArray : typesHash, should be data:typesHash

Comment: @squiroid thanks for your advice system.println gives me null

Comment: That means nothing you get use data: {
                    addArray : typesHash
                 } and check agian by simple get method .

And if possible please post your servlet code .

Comment: Hey follow first this tutorial http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/09/angular-javascript-framework-interacting-with-java-servlet-backend/ .First of you need to little alter your front end code and small changes in servlet will help you.

Comment: Thanks  your link helped me a lot please post it as an answer then I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can do it like this :-

```
 $http({
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      url: "http://localhost:8080/purchase/AddInfo",
      data: { addArray : typesHash } 


        })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                 typesHash.push( {id:data.id,name : data.name, price : data.price,unit:2.5 });
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 

            });
```

Source :-http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/09/angular-javascript-framework-interacting-with-java-servlet-backend/

Comment: Thanks a lot I learnt a lot from your this, just a quick question while a go I asked a question and you solved the problem now there is another problem related to that , can you please take a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397305/when-i-put-ng-controller-in-div-instead-of-body-autocomplete-stops-working

Answer (score 0):

HTTP has several methods in it:
'GET' - allows you to accept data from a the requested server.
'POST' - allows you to send data to the server and accept.
'PUT' - update data
etc...

try this code:

```
$http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/purchase/AddInfo",
                {addArray: typesHash}

        })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                 typesHash.push( {id:data.id,name : data.name, price : data.price,unit:2.5 });
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 

            });
```

Comment: Thank you but when I try to get in my servlet I can not ... How can I get it in servlet?

Comment: what is the error that the server returning you? maybe you need to define a specific server side code for the a post request? i am not so familiar with java based servers as it is a very old and an unefficient technolegy.

Comment: I usually get the parameter like this :String actionType = request.getParameter("addArray"); and in javascript I have addArray:typeHash  but I do not know how to gte it in this case

Comment: first of all take a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http . i can see that your server side is asking for the param 'addArray'? if that so you should send this object in the post request params: {addArray: 'your data'}

Comment: Thank you but I get null now when I try what you said please see my update

Comment: you need to send your data as an array or as an object. try: {addArray: typesHash}. what does your server side does after he get the information? does he return anything at all?

Comment: Do you mean this : addArray : [typesHash] if yes sill I get null

Comment: when I try that I get this error::The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: maybe try this: {'addArray': typesHash}

Comment: No the same error even without running I get the same error means this is not the right format

Comment: try put a varriable in the left side of the object? you are getting this error in the client correct?

Comment: maybe try as an array? [{data: data}]

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem

Comment: I have searched your error. this seems to be an error of your client engine. try to find how to solve this error in java.