# when I put ng-controller in div instead of body autocomplete stops working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have a textbox with autocomplete capability and after clicking on click me button the text in autocomplete is added as in the table , here is the link that works perfectly fine,

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('Service', function() {
    var typesHash = [ {
        id :1,
        name : 'lemon',
        price : 100,
        unit : 2.5
    }, {
        id : 2,
        name : 'meat',
        price : 200,
        unit : 3.3
    } ];

    var localId = 3;
    availableTags = [
                      "ActionScript",
                      "AppleScript",
                      "Asp",
                      "BASIC",
                      "C",
                      "C++",
                      "Clojure",
                      "COBOL",
                      "ColdFusion",
                      "Erlang",
                      "Fortran",
                      "Groovy",
                      "Haskell",
                      "Java",
                      "JavaScript",
                      "Lisp",
                      "Perl",
                      "PHP",
                      "Python",
                      "Ruby",
                      "Scala",
                      "Scheme"
                    ];
    var service = {
        addTable : addTable,
        getData : getData,
        complete:complete


    };
    return service;
    function complete($scope){
        $( "#txt" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,
          messages: {
              noResults: '',
              results: function() {}
          }
        });
        $("#txt" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
         $scope.tableTools.inputData=ui.item.value;
        } );
        } 
    function addTable(name,price) {
        typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:name, price:price,unit:1});
    }
    function getData() {
        return typesHash;
    }
});
app.controller('table', function(Service,$scope) {
    //get the return data from getData funtion in factory
    this.typesHash = Service.getData();
    //get the addtable function from factory 
    this.addTable = Service.addTable;
    this.complete=Service.complete($scope);
});
```

[working link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mLxno4jIHex0zdVVzXpt?p=preview)

but as soon as I put ng-controller="table as tableTools" in the div instead of body then autocompleting of text box start acting funny and it does not work properly

[not working link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8eZ5uYOT3Vu2MGbMqieY?p=preview)

can anyone explain the reason and tell me how I can fix it in a way that even by putting ng-controller="table as tableTools" inside div it works?

***Update:***

here is the error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'inputData' of undefined**

for this line:

```
$scope.tableTools.inputData = ui.item.value;
```

(remember the problem starts after you click on suggested text)

Comment: Hey can i ask you one question why you are using two declaration of same controller on the same page.

Comment: @squiroid Thanks for your answer since I have two different div not inside eachother then I have to do that or I can put it body what if I need to use some other controller this I should ude many controller in Body but I think it is not good to put many ngcontroller boby tag what do you think?

Comment: Yes you can use other controllers as well but that controller will act as a child of main controller in the body and have different defination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is hidden in missunderstanding of the `angularjs` object life-cycles.

The most important here to know is:

- `services` *(factory/provider ... different creation, but at the end the same)* are **singletons**
- `controllers` are **instantiated** per each **view**. *(There are many, multi instances of one controller through the angular app life time..)*

So what happened?

There is one service:

```
app.factory('Service', function() {
   ...
```

and there is one controller passing its scope into that service

```
app.controller('table', function(Service,$scope) {
    ...
    this.complete=Service.complete($scope);
```

And on the page we can see:

```
// first usage of controller
// its first instance is created, $scope is passed
<div class="row commonRow" ng-controller="table as tableTools">

// second usage
// different instance is created... and it also passes the §scope
<tbody ng-controller="table as iterateTb">
```

But as described above - **service is only one**. While first controller passes its `$scope`, the second does after while as well.. and that is causing the issue.

We can use services inside of controllers. That is the design principle of angular. But we should not pass the $scope...

Comment: Thank you So if I do not pass the scope I can solve this scenario can you give a plnkr link to show it?

Comment: So here you are: http://plnkr.co/edit/DeTy6N8p05OdMwO5pHNb?p=preview. The most important pieces: There is a brand new **`$scope.Model = {}`** to be used for referencing our values (MVC right?;) and alose, the method `.complete()` is now sitting inside of *controller*, where it belongs to... does it help?

Comment: so now the complete() function is in controller instead of factory and this way we avoid sending the $scope to factory which is not a good practice am I right?

Comment: I would say: MVC (the pattern behind angular) is: Model should represent the business domain. View is there to provide binding among input fields and the model. Controller should give some Actions to that all... Hope it helps a bit ;) And also - Services are there to help us to interact with backend, do some special stuff (localize, url routing)... They are singletons, and could do lot of magic from applicaiton point of view. MVC is there for single parts (usually wrapped in directives)

Comment: thank u just another question : for checking my understanding is it like this that his line <tbody ng-controller="table as iterateTb"> overwrite the scope in service and that is why I get that problem?

Comment: Thanks for your perfect explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have two controller on the same page with two differenct element therefore scope is not binding properly.

The best code for you to do this is :-

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.factory('Service', function() {
        var typesHash = [ {
            id :1,
            name : 'lemon',
            price : 100,
            unit : 2.5
        }, {
            id : 2,
            name : 'meat',
            price : 200,
            unit : 3.3
        } ];

        var localId = 3;
        availableTags = [
                          "ActionScript",
                          "AppleScript",
                          "Asp",
                          "BASIC",
                          "C",
                          "C++",
                          "Clojure",
                          "COBOL",
                          "ColdFusion",
                          "Erlang",
                          "Fortran",
                          "Groovy",
                          "Haskell",
                          "Java",
                          "JavaScript",
                          "Lisp",
                          "Perl",
                          "PHP",
                          "Python",
                          "Ruby",
                          "Scala",
                          "Scheme"
                        ];
        var service = {
            addTable : addTable,
            getData : getData,
            complete:complete


        };
        return service;
        function complete($scope){
            $( "#txt" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags,
              messages: {
                  noResults: '',
                  results: function() {}
              }
            });
            $("#txt" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
              console.log($scope);
             $scope.tableTools.inputData=ui.item.value;
            } );
            } 
        function addTable(name,price) {
            typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:name, price:price,unit:1});
        }
        function getData() {
            return typesHash;
        }
    });
    app.controller('table', function(Service,$scope) {
        //get the return data from getData funtion in factory
        this.typesHash = Service.getData();
        //get the addtable function from factory 
        this.addTable = Service.addTable;
        this.complete=Service.complete($scope);
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="table as tableTools" >
    <form >
      <div class="row commonRow"  >
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-right">
          item:
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
         <input id="txt" type="text" style="width: 100%;" ng-keyup="tableTools.complete()" ng-model="tableTools.inputData">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="tableTools.addTable(tableTools.inputData);tableTools.inputData=''">
                click me
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </form>

    <div class="row commonRow">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>item</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody> <!--No need for controller here-->
            <tr ng-repeat="x in tableTools.typesHash track by x.id">
              <td>
                <div>{{x.name}}</div>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QxsptDuAkKMl9ad9VDIl?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot squiroid and sorry that I sometimes bug you a lot in this forum and ask you a lot question when I started angular I knew nothing but from many of your answers I learnt angular a bit. :).

Comment: Its fine happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
$scope.tableTools={}
```

right below

```
function complete($scope){
```

the second one works as expected.

> can anyone explain the reason

As long as the object ‘$scope.tableTools‘ has not been defined, you cannot successfully add attributes to it

Comment: can you confirm your second link really does not work for you? Or could it be you need to reload your plkr page or something?

Comment: in the first one if you for example write ac then autocomplete with actionscript comes up and after clicking on that the textbox fills properly but in the second link after clciking on actionscript the textbox does not fill , also I am using chrome

Comment: I checked those links and he first one is working but the second is not working , remember the problem starts after you click on suggested text

Comment: ok, sorry I am a poor reader, I understand the question now... Will look into it...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I wish I could accept all of the answers :)